Portable 2nd Laptop Monitor with Xubuntu
I recently purchased a YXK 15.6” portable display on Amazon. It has a usb-c to usb-c cable connection and also a hdmi to a smaller hdmi cable connection option.
When I connect it via usb-c to my MSI bravo laptop running windows I can use it as a second display.
When I run xubuntu via virtual box I cannot get the ubuntu OS to acknowledge the 2nd monitor. I can grab the virtual machine and drag it to either monitor but cannot use both monitors together from within xubuntu.
I tried going to settings->display and I’ve turned on the options to configure new displays when connected but the second display doe not appear as an option.
Does anyone know how to get this monitor working so I can extend my xubuntu desktop to the second screen?
